# Angular 1.5 component templateUrl not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, gulp, components

I have just started using Angular 1.5 components and have the following snippet of code

```
angular.module('vizzle').component('teacher', {
  bindings: {},
  /* @ngInject */
  templateUrl: '/app/components/teacher/teacher.component.html',
  /* @ngInject */
  controller: function($state, $timeout, UserProfileService, TeacherService){
    //controller code in here
  }
});
```

When I run my application on my local machine using gulp serve, it is served from .tmp/serve and all works fine. However, when I gulp build and then gulp serve:dist, it is unable to resolve the templateUrl saying it can't find it. I have used the exact same code above but with a directive and it works fine. Any ideas how I can get templateUrl to work with Angular 1.5 component?